# Load php before html page load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, load

I want to first load my php code to get some values ​​and then load my web html with the values ​​already loaded. This is possible? I am looking to do this, since I want to call my php code without using Ajax and at the same time the values ​​obtained by the Php will be loaded in my web html.

Like this:
Load www.example.com -> redirect to www.example.com/index.php

```
---index.php---
<?php
//do something
include("YourHtmlWeb.html");
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'YourFunction("hi");',
     '</script>';
exit;
?>

---Html-javascript---
<script type="text/javascript">
        function YourFunction(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side. No way to get anything server-side without a network request.

Comment: This is usually done by linking directly to the PHP script, and it returns the HTML with the values filled in.

Comment: Doesn't the server process the PHP before it sends any HTML to the client? That means everything matches your question. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: I think you didn't explain what you are trying to do in a proper way!
please provide more context!

Comment: I have included an example of code. This code is functional but I do not think it is the most efficient way to do it

Comment: In the example I first load my PHP code, execute certain functions, call my html page, send the obtained data and cut the connection.

Comment: you should include the definition of the javascript fuction in the php part or else  i think it would be undefined? did you test this already?